# How to add more number of users in the custom object record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trigger, user

**UseCase:**
There is custom object called Business Meeting with the fields start time, end time, Date, Subject. 
In this I also want to add users who are all attending the business meeting while creating new meeting record.

**Workaround solution 1:**
Created a lookup on the custom object called Attendees, But we can add only one user as attendee per meeting record.

**Workaround  solution 2:** 
Tried to create lookup on the user object so that we can related list on the Business meeting. But we cant create lookup relationship on the user object.

**Workaround Solution 3:**
Tried using the event object as it has an inbuilt feature of adding an attendees. But attendees cant be added in the lightning experience view which can be added only using **lightning sync**. Our company has security restrictions with lightning sync.

Could you please provide a solution to this to add multiple users in the record who are all attending the meeting?

Comment: If you have Attendees object you can create multiple attendees which would be linked to a business meeting record. What is the problem in this case?

Comment: Attendess should be the users in the salesforce, if we attendees object how we can add the users.

Comment: You can add a lookup of User in Attendees object. I am quite sure that it would be many to many relationship between User and Business meeting as one user can attend many meetings and vice versa.

Comment: If you have campaign object you can create multiple campaign members

Comment: @AshwiniDengi Your suggestion doesn't seem to be any useful in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In **attendees** object create a lookup fields to **user** object and **meeting** object. Create a new button on **meeting** detail page to show `visualforce`page in that you can listing list of users in multi select pick list. Then have a save button on your `visualforce` page, on save action you can create new **attendees** records that lookup with **meeting** object equivalent to selected users.  So you have list of users under meeting object.

Comment: Maybe you should add a link to the [documentation of "junction object"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.relationships_manytomany.htm&type=5) to your answer ;-)